# Local traffic not proxied via Java ZAP API by ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, zap

I am quite new to ZAP and I have to use ZAP java API to perform security tests on a web application, using Selenium to navigate on a browser, creating traffic for ZAP. I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers version 2019-03 (4.11.0) with Java jdk-1.8.0_212 and Maven 3.5.3, and 3 imported libraries: harlib version 1.1.1 (edu.umass.cs.benchlab harlib), zap api version 1.7.0 (org.owasp zaproxy-api) and proxy version 2.4.2 snapshot (net.continuumsecurity zap-java-api)

I followed this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/automate-zap-security-tests-with-selenium-webdrive-1, which worked. Just to recap, it is using 3 classes: one to instantiate the web browser (BrowserDriverFactory.java), one to actually store all the navigation functions and parameters (WebSiteNavigation.java) and one to create the ZAP proxy, configure it and perform the security tests as @Test functions (ZapSecurityTest.java).

I am having a bit of a problem proxying my local application: : **it seems that my local application does not use the ZAP proxy even though I the chromedriver is well aware of the proxy (I see the non local traffic in ZAP UI).** The weird thing is that I even explicitly added my local URL to the context and set this to in scope:

```java
clientapi.context.includeInContext(contextName, 
 java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(WebSiteNavigation.BASE_URL));

clientapi.context.setContextInScope(contextName, "true");
```

After doing that and navigating on my local app, I see the related non local traffic in ZAP UI but not the local one. And when I check what clientapi.context.urls(contextName) returns, it is empty.

I create my proxy with:

```java
private static Proxy createZapProxyConfiguration() {
       Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
       proxy.setHttpProxy(ZAP_PROXYHOST + ":" + ZAP_PROXYPORT);
       proxy.setSslProxy(ZAP_PROXYHOST + ":" + ZAP_PROXYPORT);
       return proxy;
}
```

Which is called by:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Configure ZAP Scanner
    zapScanner = new ZAProxyScanner(ZAP_PROXYHOST, ZAP_PROXYPORT,  
     ZAP_APIKEY);
    clientapi = new ClientApi(ZAP_PROXYHOST, ZAP_PROXYPORT);   

    // Start new session
    zapScanner.clear();
    log.info("Started a new session: Scanner");

    // Create ZAP API client
    zapSpider = (Spider) zapScanner;

    // Create driver object
    driver = BrowserDriverFactory.createChromeDriver 
     (createZapProxyConfiguration(), BROWSER_DRIVER_PATH);
    siteNavigation = new WebSiteNavigation(driver);
}
```

Which also calls :

```java
public static WebDriver createChromeDriver(Proxy proxy, String path) {
       // Set proxy in the chrome browser
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
       capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

       // Set system property for chrome driver with the path
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.merge(capabilities);
       return new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

Weirdly enough, a few days ago when I first set this up, it was working like a charm… I then tried to automate the authentication process, and since then, it does not work…

**Am I missing something here? I am at least looking at the right place?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome by default does not proxy requests sent to localhost by default, so if this is your case you need to pass an additional flag to the chrome driver. This is how it is configured using JSON:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    proxy: proxy
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>']
    }
  },
```

The same can be done using Java API.

Comment: Thank you it worked ! I just added this line `options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>");` in my function createChromeDriver.

Comment: Happy to hear so! I was stuck with the same issue and thc202 helped me solve it out. Not so easy to find out...